# how to find the smallest integer in a list?

Tags: python

```
def big_diff(nums): 
  big = 0
  for i in nums:
    if i > big:
      big = i
  small = 1000000000
  for j in nums:
    if j < small:
      small = j
  return big - small
```

I
was wondering if there is any better way to find the smallest integer in a list in a similar way I did for the biggest integer?

Comment: Why not just use `min` and `max`?

Comment: this will fail for nums = [1000000001, 1000000002]

Comment: @anon01 yes it will, but that's actually easy to fix.

Comment: sure, just pointing out that randomly initialized data is not a great idea

Comment: `min` and `max` are definitely the way to go. If you want to fix your code so you can understand how to do it yourself, replace `big = 0` with `big = -math.inf` and `small = 1000000000` with `small = math.inf` (with `import math`, of course).

Comment: @Amadan integers in Python are unbounded, so there's a possibility that you could have an integer greater than `math.inf`.  It appears that Python does the comparison by converting the integer to floating point, but I don't know if that's guaranteed.

Comment: @MarkRansom AFAIK there is no possibility that you could have an integer greater than `math.inf`; there is by definition nothing that is greater than `math.inf` (unless someone has "creative fun" defining `WeirdClass.__gt__`). Integers are unbounded, but every single one of them will be smaller than `math.inf`.

Comment: @Amadan `math.inf` is a floating point concept that really isn't convertible to an integer in any way.  There's no integer equivalent.

Comment: Is there some reason you couldn't use the `max` and `min` functions, or did you just not know about them?

Comment: @MarkRansom While `math.inf` is a floating point number, infinity as such is a _mathemathics_ concept. Python devs say numeric comparison is a nightmare for precisely the reasons you cite, but they _did_ implement it. [Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Objects/floatobject.c#L392) is the "nothing is greater the infinity" code (commented with "If `i` is an infinity, its magnitude exceeds any finite integer, so it doesn't matter which int we compare `i` with. If `i` is a `NaN`, similarly.")

Comment: @Amadan thanks for digging into this so thoroughly and providing a link, very illuminating.  Of course it only applies to CPython, no guarantee that other implementations will be as clever.

Answer (score 3):

Use `min()` to get the smallest number

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1]
min(numbers)
#-1
```

Use `max()` to get the largest number

```
max(numbers)
#9
```

You can use `mean()` to get the average of a list

```
from statistics import mean

mean(numbers)
#4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def big_diff(nums):
    if len(nums) < 2:
        raise ValueError("The input list must have at least two elements")

    biggest = smallest = nums[0]
    for num in nums:
        if num > biggest:
            biggest = num
            continue
        if num < smallest:
            smallest = num
            continue

    return biggest - smallest
```

Here's another way to do the same thing:

```
def big_diff(nums):
    N = max(nums)
    n = min(nums)
    return N-n
```